# What is the appropriate .NET exception type when a command is issued for an entity that cannot be found?

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design

Many of my application service layer methods go something like this:

```
    public class Command
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Repository
    {
        public Entity Load(int id)
        {
            // the usual stuff here
        }
    }

    public class AppService
    {
        public void Execute(Command command)
        {
            var entity = new Repository().Load(command.Id);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                // what type of exception do I throw here?
            }
        }
    }
```

What type of exception should I throw if the client has issued a command for an entity that cannot be found?  [The InvalidOperationException spec on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) refers to "object state" not being valid.  Seems like that's not really applicable here - it's really just a bad command.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would favor `InvalidOperationException` as this makes semantic sense. The *state* of the `Command` is bad as its `Id` is not valid.

Also, I find providing parity with the .Net Framework is helpful for developers who join your project later. Looking to how Microsoft handles similar situations, such as [`Enumerable.Single<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) or [`EntityReference<TEntity>.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896375.aspx) we find they use `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: This answer FTW because that's what the .NET Framework does.  In situations where small-scale design is ambiguous like this I like to go with whatever the Framework does.

Answer (score 3):

If it were me, I would probably hand roll my own custom Exception to handle this case (if an Exception is even really necessary).

If I was feeling lazy, I would probably make use of [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) since the command argument is technically invalid since the entity it references doesn't exist.

Comment: +1, if the `Id`s are truly mutable `ArgumentException` is the way to go.

Comment: In this case, the Ids are immutable.  Good point about whether it's actually necessary... I think it's reasonable to say they are because these app service methods will be hit by third party systems via WCF web methods and I have no idea how stale their data may be.

Comment: I'd stray towards favoring the `InvalidOperationException`, but I could be persuaded. To me, an argument exception seems like it would be something you'd throw *before* trying to do anything with it. Once I've used it, seems like a different (although perhaps related) problem.

Comment: @Josh: I've updated the code in your question to show that `Command.Id` is immutable. I'd made the assumption of that when I answered, but realized it could use clarification after reading @Justin's answer.

Comment: Thanks.  That was my bad.  It should've been public readonly int Id;

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [ApplicationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception.aspx), as this is non-fatal application exception. It just so happen, that there's no data.

Maybe a better approach would be to go with your own exceptions, derived from Exception class if you want to have a better control.

Comment: -1: `ApplicationException` shouldn't be used. It was created back in .NET 1.0 days when it was thought there should be one exception hierarchy  under `SystemException` and one under `ApplicationException`. That has turned out not to be useful.

Comment: Specifically, the MSDN docs on Best Practices for Handling Exceptions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx) state: For most applications, derive custom exceptions from the Exception class. It was originally thought that custom exceptions should derive from the ApplicationException class; however in practice this has not been found to add significant value.

Comment: pls, revert the (-1). The right statement is about the "custom" exceptions. It was thought they to be derived from ApplicationException. No one said it shouldn't be ApplicationException in it's original form. It's not deprecated, and it's definition is exactly for non-fatal application errors. Of course, if you point out that somewhere its written that you shouldn't use it at all, pls provide a link. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that the stuff I quoted from MSDN indicates that ApplicationException shouldn't be used at all anymore.

Comment: I believe that "for most" does not mean "for all". And I fixed my answer long before the -1 to point out the custom exceptions. Oh, anyway ... whatever makes you happy.

Comment: I wasn't the one who -1-ed you, though.  I'll vote you back up.

Comment: Taking `ApplicationException` for its original intention of being the common base class of custom exceptions, then this would be like throwing `Exception` when something more derived would be more appropriate. In other words, you should throw the most descriptive and fitting exception, just like you would only catch a narrowly defined exception you could actually handle and not any particular exception that came your way.